# Activity not recreated after device rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation

I am new to android and wanted to solve a really basic problem. I am trying to expecting that my Main activity is recreated and onCreate method is called again when the emulator is rotated but this is not happening. I have added the necessary code in Manifest file.

Here is the code for Manifest file.

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am using the following SDK versions

```
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 29
compileSdkVersion 29
```

Can someone guide why the activity lifecycle methods are not called?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recreate activity when the device rotates then remove this line: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"`  from the activity tag of the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config):

> `android:configChanges`
>
> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself.  When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted.

By declaring

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"
```

you are effectively saying that you'll handle orientation changes yourself, and *don't* want your activity to be recreated.

Just remove `orientation` (and maybe the entire attribute, unless you do want to handle `screenLayout`) to get the default behaviour, which is to recreate the activity.

Comment: Initially, i have not added this line and still i am not getting the activity to rotate so that why i thought to try these but i guess i was wrong but the problem still exists even if i remove them.

Comment: Is your device locked to portrait mode in settings?

Comment: I am trying on emulator and it does gets rotation but the lifecycle methods are not being called.